# Setting 'buildNumber' and 'versionNumber' while building APK from gradle

Tags: android, gradle, command-line, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building APKs from command line as follows

```
./gradlew assembleProductionRelease
```

Are there any configuration params which will allow to add `buildNumber` and `versionNumber` to APK file name automatically? By default APK file will be named as `app-production-release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try/adapt this code (add it to your build.gradle):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def sep = '_'
            def version = variant.versionName
            def build = variant.versionCode
            outputFileName = "${rootProject.name}${sep}" +
                    "${variant.buildType.name}${sep}" +
                    "${version}${sep}" +
                    "build${sep}${build}.apk"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!